# MIMD/MPMD parallelism

Tags: parallel-processing, hpc, distributed-system

Assume that there is a globally shared data block that is being used by a set of machines in a cluster.

If it is a distributed memory model, say the whole structure is sent to every node in the cluster.

Each node in the cluster performs different operations to the parts of the shared data block in parallel.

My question is: can it be identified as a Multiple Instruction, Multiple Data (MIMD) model since the whole data block is shared by/transferred to every node in the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply the same operation to different pieces of data then you have data-level parallelism, which according to [Flynn's Taxonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flynn%27s_taxonomy) is equivalent to [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) (Single Instruction, Multiple Data streams), typically applied in GPU processing.

Multiple Instruction, Multiple Data ([MIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMD)) entail that different processors may be executing different instructions on different data.

So according to the definitions, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Actually, I realized that in the Wikipedia article for Flynn's Taxonomy, it is stated that "Distributed systems are generally recognized to be MIMD architectures".

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, and yes distributed systems normally execute in MIMD pattern. But here my confusion was, since the same data block is sent to every worker node(even though different parts of the block is used) what the technically correct word for that is.